# Is there a way how to search filename in Minio API/SDK?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I'm trying to use Minio as storage for our manufacturing data. I planned to create a **bucket with name "color"** and I want to store measurement data file **160f33fa03fa8.csv**(its just a unique id from our other system) and it will be nice to insert date to the filename to organize it like **2020_04_160f33fa03fa8.csv** or create sub folders **color/2020/04/160f33fa03fa8.csv**.

Its any way how to search with API/SDK for filename **160f33fa03fa8.csv** without knowing a specific path? Or is any way how to store date on the object and simple search, for example, all objects with date **2020/04**?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Minio client `mc` for this;

```
mc find myminio/mybucket --name "*160f33fa03fa8.csv"
```

source: https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html